# Is there a way to use a specific locale for a SF Symbol which is different from the current locale?

Tags: ios, swift, sf-symbols

I have an app which supports both English and Japanese locales. There, I am creating a `button` and set an `UIImage` to it, which uses a `SF Symbol`.

```
let image = UIImage(systemName: "textbox")!.withConfiguration(UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 30, weight: .regular))
button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
```

Now for English and Japanese locales, the button looks like below.
[image]

I have a requirement to stop localisation happening for the image of this specific `button`. For both locales, I want the `SF Symbol` now appears for English to be shown in the `button`. Is there a way to achieve this with `SF Symbols` ?

Comment: One possible solution you could try is to export the symbol from the SF Symbol app and add it as an asset to your project. You should check that there is no copyright issues or similar with doing this.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I checked the Apple documentation and we are allowed to export a SF Symbol then customize it and use. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll go with this approach. 

Documentation -> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/creating_custom_symbol_images_for_your_app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If someone wants to do this for any locale except English, then the [answer from @wakel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69000449/2484716) would be the better option.

For locale English, as @JoakimDanielson suggested in a comment, I have done this by downloading SF Symbols app and by exporting the required `SF Symbol` as a `custom symbol template`

**SF Symbols app -> File -> Export Custom Symbol Template**

This custom symbol is without any locales by default, which can be added to `Assets` of the project. Once it has added, you can use it as any other image asset you added using `UIImage(named:)`

```
let image = UIImage(named: "textbox")!.withConfiguration(UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 30, weight: .regular))
button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
```

The official Apple documentation for exporting symbols from SF Symbols app is here
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/creating_custom_symbol_images_for_your_app

Answer (score 7):

## 2023 Update

On iOS 17+ it is now possible to specify a `Locale` when retrieving an SF symbol:

```
UIImage(systemName: "textbox", withConfiguration: .init(locale: .init(identifier: "en-US")))
```

## Original answer

It seems like the only way to force a specific language for an SF Symbol is by appending a language code, so in case of `textbox`:

```
UIImage(systemName: "textbox")
UIImage(systemName: "textbox.ar")
UIImage(systemName: "textbox.he")
UIImage(systemName: "textbox.hi")
UIImage(systemName: "textbox.ja")
UIImage(systemName: "textbox.ko")
UIImage(systemName: "textbox.th")
UIImage(systemName: "textbox.zh")
UIImage(systemName: "textbox.zh.traditional")
```

However, this won't allow you to force the English version, but only non-English ones. You are probably out of luck when loading SF Symbols through Apple's APIs. I would go for Joakim Danielson's approach and try to export the default icon.

Comment: Didn't know that we could append locale to the SF symbols. Too bad this cannot be done for English though :)

Comment: Why can't this be done for English? Does `"textbox.en"` not work? BTW - the SF Symbol has been renamed to "character.textbox" as of iOS 14.5.

Comment: @HangarRash Exactly, when trying to use `textbox.en` no SF Symbol can be found.